# Find the particular solution of $y''+y=\cos(t)\cos(2t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the particular solution of $L[y]=y''+y=\cos(t)\cos(2t)$

Here my steps:

**Homogeneous:** $y''+y=0$

**Roots** $+i$ and $-i$

**General solution**: $y(t)=c_1\cos(t)+c_2\sin(t)+\psi(t)$

Since we are dealing with cosine then we can rewrite the right hand side as:

$y''+y=e^{it}e^{2it}=e^{{it}(1+2)}v$

Now to guess:

Let:

$\psi=e^{{it}(1+2)}v$

$\psi'=e^{{it}(1+2)}v'+3ie^{{it}(1+2)}v$

$\psi''=e^{{it}(1+2)}v''+3ie^{{it}(1+2)}v'+3ie^{{it}(1+2)}v'-9e^{{it}(1+2)}v$

**Plug back into $L[y]$:**

$L[y]=e^{{it}(1+2)}v''+6ie^{{it}(1+2)}v'-9e^{{it}(1+2)}v+e^{{it}(1+2)}v=e^{{it}(1+2)}v$

Dividing each side by $e^{{it}(1+2)}$

**We obtain:**

$L[y]=v''+6iv'-9v+v=v''+6iv'-8v=1$

**Let**:

$v(t)=a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2$

$v'(t)=a_1+2ta_2$

$v''(t)=2a_2$

**Plug back into:**

$L[y]=v''+6iv'-9v+v=v''+6iv'-8v=1$

$L[y]=2a_2+6ia_1+12ita_2-8a_0-8a_1t-8a_2t^2=1$

**Equating coefficients:**
$$2a_2+6ia_1-8a_0=1$$
$$ 12ia_2-8a_1=0$$
$$-8a_2=0$$

from there I got:

$$ a_2=0$$
$$ a_1=0$$
$$a_0=\frac{-1}{8}$$

**Plugging back into $v(t)$**

$$v(t)=\frac{-1}{8}$$

**Plugging back into $\psi=e^{{it}(1+2)}v$**

$$\psi=e^{{it}(1+2)}\frac{-1}{8}$$

Replacing the exponential with sine and cosines. The particular solution must be contain real values since the right hand side has cosine.

$$\psi=[\cos(t)+i\sin(t)][\cos(2t)+i\sin(2t)]\frac{-1}{8}$$

I only multiplied the real parts:

$$\psi=\frac{-1}{8}[\cos(t)\cos(2t)-\sin(t)\sin(2t)]$$

The inside looks like the sum and angle formula so we have:

$$\psi=\frac{-1}{8}\cos(2t+t)$$

but sadly, I went wrong since the answer key says:

$\psi(t)=-\frac{1}{16}\cos(3t)+\frac{1}{4}t\sin(t)$

Honestly, I'm not sure where I went wrong

Comment: When you say "...we can rewrite the right hand side as..." you're assuming that $\cos t = e^{it}$ and $\cos 2t = e^{2it}$. These are not valid identities, because $\cos t = \frac12 (e^{it} + e^{-it})$.

Comment: right after you made that mistake, you started writing (1+2) instead of 3 , that was your subconscious telling you it wasn't happy about something.

Comment: @WW1 Freudian calculus? :)

Comment: I think the general idea is correct. If the right side were only $\cos(2t)$, then finding $y_p$ for $e^{i2t}$ and using the real part of that solution is shorter than the fully real way. However, $Re(a·b)\ne Re(a)·Re(b)$

Comment: I GOT IT GUYS! THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$\cos t \cos 2t=\frac{1}{2}(\cos3t+\cos t)$ so that $$y_h=c_1\cos t+c_2\cos t$$ and $$y_{p_1}=A\cos 3t+B\sin 3t$$and $$y_{p_2}=E\cos t+F\sin t$$ therefore $$y_p=y_{p_1}+y_{p_2}$$

Comment: You need to multiply $y_{p_2}$ with $t$ since repeated eigenvalue.

Comment: The identity was where I went wrong. Thanks!!!